# How do make it so that every time the incremental load in dbt runs it just updates the new rows from when it last ran?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

How do make it so that every time the incremental load in dbt runs it just updates the new rows from when it last ran?

```
{% if is_incremental() %}

    /* code */

    {% endif %}
```

Comment: you are using macros to achieve this, you didn't mention. Can you please share more details?

Answer (score 6):

Your two main resources for doing this are going to be in the dbt docs already:

1. How to build incremental models in dbt:
   https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models/
2. Incremental models particular to bigquery:
   https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs/#merge-behavior-incremental-models

Most likely the model will look something like:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental'
    )
}}

select <columns>
from <my_table>
{% if is_incremental() %}
  where <my_table>.<record_update_timestamp> >= (
      select max(<my_table>.<record_update_timestamp>) from {{ this }}
  )
  {% endif %}
```

Full example in from docs in:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models/#defining-a-uniqueness-constraint-optional